# Proving that a function is not injective.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

The proof asks for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$ prove that it is neither injective nor surjective.

My thoughts are to approach this using a proof by contradiction, and say I will prove that the function is injective. I can get to the step where $a^2=b^2$ and I know the square root of a variable is $\pm$ that variable. So would my final step be to say that $\pm a \neq \pm b$?

Comment: I think it's easier to exhibit $x\neq y$ with $f(x)=f(y)$.  All you need is one such pair to prove $f$ isn't injective.

Comment: Did you ever see an injective even function?

Comment: I think stating "$\pm a = \pm b$" is ambiguous.  It means $a$ *could* equal $b$ and therefore this isn't a proof that there exist any that don't.  I'd prefer it if you specifically pointed out: and therefore if $b =-a\ne a$ we have $f(b)=f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to prove that a function is not injective is to explicitly name distinct elements of the domain that map to the same place.

The easiest way to prove that a function is not surjective is to explicitly name an element of the codomain that is not mapped to.

In this case, $$f(1) = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  f(-1) = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2},$$ and there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ \frac{1}{x^2 +1} = -5,$$ so $-5 \in \mathbb{R}$ is not mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample suffices: $1 \neq -1$ but $f(1) = f(-1)= \frac12$ so $f$ is not injective.

Also, $f(x)$ never assumes the value $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is not surjective, and moreover all $f(x) >0$, so all negative values are also never assumed.

$f$ would be bijective as a function from $(0,\infty) \to (0,1)$..

Answer (score 1):

Look at $f(1)=f(-1)$. These are the same, therefore, f cannot be injective.

To prove it is not surjective, try to find an x such that $f(x)>1$, say 2. Then f(x)=2 means solving $x^2=-1/2$ which has no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just demonstrate that there is some element $y$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\neq y$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, and also find two numbers $x_1\neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Could you do this for the function $x\mapsto x^2$ (just think of the graph)? If so the how about for the function $x\mapsto x^2+1$? What about the function $x\mapsto 1/x$? Moving from these functions to $f$ should then be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your proof is something like:

Let $f(a) = f(b)$ so

$\frac 1{a^2 +1} = \frac 1{b^2 + 1}$

.....

$a^2 = b^2$

so $\pm a = \pm b$,

and you are asking if that completes the proof.

Well, not really but mostly, in my opinion.  You need to explicitely state $a \ne b$ *IS* a possibility.  "$\pm a = \pm b$" seems as though you are solving an equation and have found multiple *pontential* solutions but nothing definite.  We aren't actually trying to *solve* something but prove that something could *definite* happen.

So if you concluded with the statement:

"and so if $b = -a \ne a$ we'd have a case where $f(a) = f(b)$ but $a \ne b$"

then it would be adequate, in my opinion.

.....

However I also think it'd be more direct to simply say from the start:

For any $a \ne 0$ then $a \ne -a$.  But $f(a) = f(-a)$ so $f$ is not injective.

....

or as others have pointed out a single specific counter example would do.